# how to store customized Data for doctrine?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I work with symfony2 and there i use doctrine. As Example i have a simple repository-class in my doctrine xml-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
<entity name="AllgemeinBundle\Entity\ObjektPosition" table="objekt_position" repository-class="AllgemeinBundle\Repository\ObjektPositionRepository">
<indexes>
  <index name="id_objekt_subunternehmer_position_fk2_idx" columns="id_subunternehmer"/>
  <index name="id_objekt_objektposition_idx" columns="id_objekt"/>
</indexes>
<id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
  <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
</id>
<field name="artikelnummer" type="integer" column="artikelnummer" nullable="false"/>
<field name="preisProEinheit" type="float" column="preis_pro_einheit" precision="10" scale="2" nullable="false"/>
<field name="p1Einheit" type="float" column="p1_einheit" precision="10" scale="2" nullable="false"/>
<field name="p2Einheit" type="float" column="p2_einheit" precision="10" scale="2" nullable="true"/>
<field name="p3Einheit" type="float" column="p3_einheit" precision="10" scale="2" nullable="true"/>
<field name="zusatztext" type="text" column="zusatztext" nullable="true"/>
<field name="position" type="integer" column="position" nullable="false"/>
<many-to-one field="idSubunternehmer" target-entity="Subunternehmer">
  <join-columns>
    <join-column name="id_subunternehmer" referenced-column-name="subunternehmernummer"/>
  </join-columns>
</many-to-one>
<many-to-one field="idObjekt" target-entity="Objekt">
  <join-columns>
    <join-column name="id_objekt" referenced-column-name="id"/>
  </join-columns>
</many-to-one>
```

when i am generating my entities from the database, then the repository-class would be deleted. Also some other thinks i added to the xml-file.

Is it able to save the customized data in a sperated folder or file, so that i can generate the entities as often as i like and the customized data wouldn't be lost?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using console commands, when generating entities don't mention '--no-backup' at the end of the command. So, you will be able to preserve your entity class. However you entity class will be renamed with adding '~' sign at the start of the file name. Your entity generation code will be like this, (without trailing --no-backup)

php app/console doctrine:generate:entities

Hope this helps,
Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but its not what i think. I have all the file also in an SVN-Repository, so i have always a good backup. But what i mean is, that I can store the customized datas in external files. So i dont have to edit the origin entitiy-files.